# How can i pass select sql inside IN clause of Pivot

Tags: oracle

I have below query where i am trying to achieve using pivot. Is there any way i can define a sub query inside IN clause in pivot. I tried PIVOT XML but i am not getting expected output

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT customer_ref, product_id
  FROM orders
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(product_id)
  FOR product_id IN (10, 20, 30)
)
ORDER BY customer_ref;
```

how can i define a sub query in the IN clause

```
is there any possibility for ---FOR product_id IN (select distinct product_id from orders).

I tried PIVOT XML but it was displaying xml code which is not expected output.
```

Is there any way to achieve ?

Comment: No, you have to use dynamic SQL, or an XML pivot - but then as you've seen to you have to extract the data from the XML somehow. But what will consume the output? If the number of columns in the output aren't known then it's probably only going to be readable by a human, not another process. This sort of thing might be better left to a presentation/reporting layer, rather than being done in the database.

Comment: @AlexPoole. Thanks Alex for the reply. I am trying not to hard code (10,20,30) because in future  some may get newly added. So instead of those those values can i use a select sql ?

Comment: @MTO. I hope this question is not duplicate because it has solution with XML , and i already mentioned in my question that i m not expecting any XML output.

Comment: The duplicate shows the only ways you can do this, The accepted answer uses XML but look at the other answers too. You cannot use a query inside the `in()` clause in plain SQL as you were hoping, it has to be done dynamically.